# About Dataframes

Tags: matrices, statistics, mathematical-modeling, programming

I'll be quick and straight-forward; I created a python 3 script that takes a 6x6 table, populated with [1,10] values, and a 1x6 table, also populated with [1,10] values and then either adds or multiplies their values a new 6x6 table, based on two models.

What I want to do is translate that into a mathematical model, which I have, but I don't know if I meet the right conditions because it has been 3 years since I last used models to express a process.

$$MIO=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}x_{1,1} & \cdots  & x_{1,6} \\ \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\ x_{6,1} & \cdots  & x_{6,6} \end{array}\right]$$

$$factor=\left[f_1\cdots f_6\right]$$

$$D_{factor}=[1,10]$$

$$D_{MIO}=[1,10]$$

$${Model1= 
M
I
O
+factor}$$

$${Model1= 
M
I
O
*factor}$$

So here is where you come in; do you think what I did is correct, because at this point I don't know if the right conditions are met to calculate the new table or if I should calculate the values by themselves and then populate a new table with the values

P.S I know that you are going to ask whether I'm using matrix tables, so before you ask I used dataframes which I believe are not actually matrices but vectors. So if I'm wrong on that as well, feel free to correct me.

Comment: As you requested.

Comment: A square matrix and a row vector can't be added in linear algebra.

Comment: You can't add a vector and a matrix. You'll have to explain what exactly you mean when you say you multiply and add the values of the table with the vector.

Comment: @JackM oh yeah,what I meant to say is that I calculated the new values of the 6x6 table by doing xi,1 * f1 and xi,1 + f1. Does it make sense?

Comment: @JasonStatham So you basically multiply (or add) the vector $f$ to each column of the table?

Comment: @JackM Sorry, I wanted to express a per row calculation, but basically yes

Comment: Well, it seems like your question is basically "are there standard mathematical symbols for expressing this operation", to which the answer is "no", but also more to the point the answer is "no, and who cares?". Your understanding of the problem will not somehow improve because instead of explaining your vector-matrix multiplication operation in English, you can express it in symbols.

Comment: So, I should try to understand the problem better instead of trying to find a way to express it. But that is why I'm here, to either correct me or point me to a direction, because it is the first time I'm doing something like this and I wanted someone more suitable to explain it. Otherwise I'd have to use either λ-calculus or just use functions to explain how the table is populated.

Comment: But it seems like you already understand the problem perfectly well - each row of the table is multiplied/added component-by-component with the vector $f$.

Comment: I've made a terrible mistake. I was so focused on expressing the solution using math symbols that I didn't realize that I could describe it using basic sentences. Thank you for pointing that out. Now I'm going to take a break for a the next two days.